# Copy-constructor c++: compiler can't find it when using a = b

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

I am implementing a `Vector` class. These are my source files.

`vector.h`

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

class Vector
{
 public:
    Vector();
    explicit Vector(const Vector& src);
};
#endif // VECTOR_H
```

`vector.cpp`

```
#include "vector.h"

Vector::Vector()
{
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector &src)
{
}
```

And the test program,  `main.cpp`

```
#include "vector.h"
int main()
{
   Vector a;      // calls default constructor
   Vector b(a);   // calls copy-constructor, compiles and works fine
   Vector c = a;  // should call copy-constructor, but does not compile
   return 0;
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error: `"no matching function for call to 'Vector::Vector(Vector&)'"` .

What can be going wrong here?

EDIT: Added the complete code for a minimum working example.
Thanks!

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is your copy-ctor `explicit` ?

Comment: Yeah, your copy-constructor is probably `explicit`. Can you show us a minimal working example please?

Comment: I agree, the explicitness had it uncapable of calling the copy constructor. Go ahead Piotr and answer this

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have edited, is that enough?

Comment: Yes, the problem was the "explicit" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `Vector c = a;` you are using is called a **copy-initialization**:

> #### § 8.5 Initializers `[dcl.init]` / p15
>
> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> ```
> T x = a;
> ```
>
> as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1) is called **copy-initialization.**

The problem is, your copy constructor is marked as `explicit`:

> #### § 12.3.1 Conversion by constructor `[class.conv.ctor]` / p2
>
> An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit constructors, but does so **only where the
>   direct-initialization syntax** (8.5) or where casts (5.2.9, 5.4) are explicitly used.

And what is a *direct-initialization*?

> #### § 8.5 Initializers `[dcl.init]` / p16
>
> The initialization that occurs in the forms
>
> ```
> T x(a);
> T x{a};
> ```
>
> as well as in new expressions (5.3.4), static_cast expressions (5.2.9), functional notation type conversions
>   (5.2.3), and base and member initializers (12.6.2) is called **direct-initialization.**

Please change your copy-constructor declaration from:

```
explicit Vector(const Vector& src);
```

into:

```
Vector(const Vector& src);
```

if you want to utilize the copy constructor using a copy-initialization syntax.

Answer (score -1):

That is actually calling the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

You can make one by defining void `Vector::operator=(const Vector& param);`

Comment: Vector & Vector::operator=(const Vector& param); So that assignment chaining can be implemented. a = b = c;

Comment: No, the assignment operator is not being invoked here. Look at the error message - it clearly chose a constructor to invoke.